# Vim edit file from machine B via machine A

Tags: vim, ssh, macvim, scp

For example, I have two remote machines. Let's say, A, B. 
Usually I can do vim scp://A/path/file to remote edit A's files locally.
So, is there a way to edit machine B, which can only be accessed from A, from host machine using vim directly? Thank you very much.

```
The topology:
  +---------------------------------------------------------------+
  |                                                               |
  |                                                               |
  |      +--------------+        +-----------+     +-----------+  |
  |      |              |        |           |     |           |  |
  |      |    HOST      | +----> |     A     |+--->|     B     |  |
  |      |              |        |           |     |           |  |
  |      +--------------+        +-----------+     +-----------+  |
  |                                                               |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How do you feel about using sshfs on machine A?

Comment: This is really more of a question about ssh tunneling rather than vim or programming.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Conner that this is a ssh-tunneling question but here is a possible answer anyway..

- Install *[netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)* on host *'A'*
- Add this to your $HOME/.ssh/config:

  ```
  Host RemoteHost
      Hostname B
      User UsernameOnB
      Port 22
      ProxyCommand ssh UsernameOnA@A 'nc %h %p'
  ```

You would have to replace *'A'*, *'B'*, *'UsernameOnA'* and *'UsernameOnB'* with the matching hostnames or IP addresses for *A* and *B* (and check if netcat is installad as *'nc'* or *'netcat'* I've seen both..)

After that you should be able to:

```
$ vim scp://RemoteHost/path/to/file
```

*This setup works best if you have public-key access to both systems, otherwise you will be prompted for passwords.*